# off-topic voters, please explain yourselves

Tags: discussion

I could better understand when a question is off-topic if you can explain why this question:  [Ali Express hijacking my Chrome](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93421/ali-express-hijacking-my-chrome) was put on hold as "off topic" ?

Reading the rules:

> Topics include, but are not limited to:
>
> web app hardening network security social engineering, including
>   phishing risk management policies penetration testing security tools
>   using cryptography incident response physically securing the office,
>   datacentre, information assets etc.

dealing with a virus that redirects web traffic hits on several of these.  What are you all trying to accomplish by marking this off-topic (and why can it be accomplished by just a few people)?

Answer (score 9):

> What are you all trying to accomplish by marking this off-topic

Reducing the amount of noise in the system. That a question is answerable doesn't mean that it fits into the theme of the site.

> Why can it be accomplished by just a few people?

Generally there's little contention. The same number of people that it takes to close a question can also re-open it. Most of the time that five people with enough reputation to close a question do so, they're right.

> Why [my question] was put on hold as "off topic"

It may be that it comes off as more of a support question than a real security question. That said, it reads to me like you can better frame it into incident response for a local compromise, and that's totally on-point.

Comment: I agree. The question amounts to tech support and virus remediation. None of that is listed in the suggested topic list. Answer: run an offline virus scanner, get a professional to clean the machine, or nuke and rebuild.

Comment: @schroeder Option three. Always and only option three. It's the only way to be sure.

Comment: @Iszi well, it depends on what you hope to achieve from your actions :)

Comment: @schroeder Is a trustworthy system really too much to ask for?

Comment: @Iszi Yes, when you want to investigate the current infection...